# Azure API Management backend not reachable with 2 locations

Tags: azure-api-management

I have an API Management (premium) setup in Azure that is connected to a virtual network in West Europe that contains Docker Machines that serves APIs, the APIs are reachable via IP address in the 10.0.0/16 range.

To make my setup highly available I added a virtual network in North Europe with exactly the same setup as West Europe except for the IP range, now being 11.0.0.0/16.

Now when I scale API Management to add another region my APIs are not accessible anymore. I tried the set-backend-service command to only point to one region but I can't seem to access the backends anymore. The message that I get when doing the trace from the portal is "Unable to connect to the remote server". It seems to me that when adding another location that API management doesn't know how to route to the different virtual networks.

Any idea how I can make this setup work?

Answer (score 0):

In multi-region scenario APIM runs same configuration in both regions. So for cases like yours you do need to use set-backend-service policy to conditionally override backend server address. So if your APIs at the moment setup with 10.0.X.X, you will need to add policy similar to below:

```
<choose>
    <when condition="@(context.Request.Deployment.Region == "North Europe">
        <set-backend-service url="http://11.0.Y.Y" />
    </when>
</choose>
```

That is assuming that you address your backends by IP address. If you address them by DNS then you'll need to configure your DNS server in VNET to provide correct addresses.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here was that the VNETs need to be peered. After I figured this out everything worked as advertised.